# Question on how rate of change answer came from

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

> The volume of a spherical balloon of radius r cm increases at a rate of $10\pi cm^3/s$.Find the rate of change of its radius.

The answer:
Let $V cm^3$ be the volume of the balloon at time $t$.

$$V=\frac43 \pi r^3$$

$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac43 \pi(3r^2)\frac{dr}{dt}$ (which is equal to $\frac{dV}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}$).

and so on.
What I don't get is how $\frac{dV}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}$came from.There are only three variables here,so messing them around could already get the answer.But what if there are more variables in a rate of change question?How do I write a good equation?

Comment: That’s the chain rule

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule
And more specifically I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Composites_of_more_than_two_functions

Comment: Let $V=f(a,b,c)$ with $a(t)$, $b(t)$, $c(t)$. Then $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial a}\frac{da}{dt}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial b}\frac{db}{dt}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial c}\frac{dc}{dt}$. Here $\frac{\partial V}{\partial a}$ is partial derivative, that is derivative taken when other independent variables ($b$ and $c$) are considered as constants. For example for cubic box with changeable sizes $V=abc$, $\frac{\partial V}{\partial a}=bc$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more or in another way? I haven't learned about partial derivatives yet thanks.

Comment: Let consider infinitesimal (infinitely small) change of time $dt$. Then changes of independent variables affecting volume are $da=\frac{da}{dt} dt$, $db=\frac{db}{dt} dt$, $dc=\frac{dc}{dt} dt$. Let consider change of $V$ because of changing $a$ only. Let mark this change as $d_aV=V(a+da,b,c)-V(a,b,c)$. $d_aV=\left(\lim_{\Delta a\to 0}\frac{V(a+\Delta a,b,c)-V(a,b,c)}{\Delta a}\right) da$. $\lim_{\Delta a\to 0}\frac{V(a+\Delta a,b,c)-V(a,b,c)}{\Delta a}$ is called partial derivative of $V$ with respect to $a$ and marked as $\frac{\partial V}{\partial a}$. $dV=d_aV+d_bV+d_cV$.